# How to group multiple column values and find max value of another column

Tags: excel-formula

I need to know based on the attached Excel, how to group column A and B which have duplicate values and return the MAX value/row of another column in this case column C and D.

[image: Excel sheet sample data]

Comment: Have you tried to create a pivot table from your data? doesn't that solve the problem for you?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe can be done with a simple Pivot Table.

Drag A and B into the rows, drag C and D into the Values and then change the value field settings to show the Maximum value.

You need to add column headers to the data, so you can identify the data by column name. It's not clear from the screenshot "A", "B", "C" are the Excel built-in column letters or your data headers.

You also need to clean up the data since it looks like the numbers are stored as text. You will not be able to perform any calculations like "maximum" unless you convert the text back to numbers.

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.